# what is the residue of $\frac{1}{z(1-cos(z))}$ in $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

what is the residue of $\frac{1}{z(1-cos(z))}$ in $0$?

I tried using the residual formula $Res_{z=a} f(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z)$

But then i get infty? Is there something i'm missing here?

Kees

Comment: Quite bad written. What are "residual points" in... a point?! If you are looking for the residue, please use "what is the residue" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z(1-\cos(z)) = \dfrac{z^3}{2} - \dfrac{z^5}{24} + \ldots = \dfrac{z^3}{2} \left(1 - \dfrac{z^2}{12} + \ldots\right)$, so
$$ \dfrac{1}{z(1-\cos(z))} = \dfrac{2}{z^3} \left(1 + \dfrac{z^2}{12} + \ldots\right) = \dfrac{2}{z^3} + \dfrac{1}{6z} + \ldots$$
Thus the residue is $1/6$.

Comment: i see you use the sumfunction $\frac{1}{1-z}$, but how do you see that $|z|<1$?

Comment: These are Laurent series computations with $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ "sufficiently small".

Answer (score 1):

You got infinity since the pole is *not* simple, but:

$$\frac1{z(1-\cos z)}=\frac1z\frac1{\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^4}{24}+\mathcal O(z^6)}=\frac2{z^3}\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+\mathcal (z^4)}=\frac2{z^3}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+\frac{z^4}{144}+\ldots\right)$$

and we can see we have a pole of order here.

Comment: i see you use the sumfunction $\frac{1}{1-z}$, but how do you see that $|z|<1$?

Comment: @KeesTil that's a safe assumption since we're interested in values of $\;z\;$ pretty close to zero, right?

Comment: yeah, but can't it become bigger than one since we got infty many terms?

Comment: @KeesTil I'm not sure I understand your last question: if you decide to take $\;z\;\;s.t.\;\;|z|<0.1\;$ say, how "can it become bigger"??

Comment: o i mean the term $\frac{1}{1-(\frac{z^2}{12} - (z^4))}$ and this is equal to that sum function if $|\frac{z^2}{12} - (z^4)| <1$, but i don't see why this is necesarrily true.

Comment: @KeesTil We're only interested in $\;\left|\frac{z^2}{12}\right|<1\iff |z|<2\sqrt3\;$ , and we can assume this since we're interested in the residue at the pole $\;z=0\;$ and thus $\;z\;$ can be taken such that its module is as small as we want.